# What is the right way to style an element with multiple selectors in SASS?

Tags: sass

I have some elements as such:

```
<div class="logo">
 <a href="#">LOGO HERE</a>
</div>
```

Considering the `a` tag is the only element within `.logo` is it still appropriate to write the SASS as:

```
.logo {
  a {
   //STYLES
  }
}
```

Or is normal css ok here? Eg:

```
.logo a {
 //STYLES
}
```

Both ways work, of course, but is there a preferred way when working with SASS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both will work fine in SASS. Traditionally, for readability, it's better to nest the elements, as you've listed in the first example.